# SQL(List the names of distributors who have an ‘A’ and also a ‘B’ somewhere in their names.)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
SQL> select * from distributor;

DN0  DNAME     DADDR         DPHONE
------------------------------------
D01  Hardik    Orissa        9173487
D02  Dhaval    Aanand        9898111
D03  Arjun     Baroda        9725061
D04  Bhavika   Valsad        9878451
D05  Kunal     Ahmedabad     8520852
```

I want to list the names of distributors who have both an ‘A’ and a ‘B’ somewhere in their names.

I have tried

```
select * from distributor where dname like '%b% a%' or dname like  '%a% b%';

select * from distributor where dname like '%a%' and dname like '%b%';
```

As the question says, if an ‘A’ and a ‘B’ character exists in any name from this table (distributor), that name should be displayed.

I need some help to understand this query.

The error is:

```
*//SQL> select * from distributor where dname like '%b% a%' or dname like  '%a% b%';

no rows selected

SQL> select * from distributor where dname like '%a' and '%b';
select * from distributor where dname like '%a' and '%b'
                                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator//*
```

Comment: The error clearly shows that the second SQL you posted above is not what you actually executed

Comment: For future reference, please tag your questions correctly. You don't need to tag with every single database tag you can find. If it is a generic question then sql would be fine, if specific to one rdbms then choose oracle, postgres, mysql as necessary.

Comment: Clearly the error is the spaces within the search strings. Out of curiosity, why did you have spaces in them?

Comment: Your second version `where dname like '%a%' and dname like '%b%';` should have worked. What's the problem?

Comment: table is just for info... error is diferent.. Select * from distributor; just for showing table...

Comment: As the error section contains 2 errors only tried differently... pasted here combine... so dont' get confuse..

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why yours didn't work like this:

```
select dname
from distributor
where lower(dname) like '%a%'
and lower(dname) like '%b%'
```

But this will get anyone who has an 'a' `and` a 'b'

If you use `or`, this will get everyone with an 'a' and everyone with a 'b'

Comment: if you look at the OP's query with the OR, they're looking for a pattern of an `a` followed by a `b` or a `b` followed by an `a`, so the last part of your answer doesn't quite fit with the question.

Comment: @Boneist While OP does this in the query, I think it is out of confusion. The description does not mention any order, and the use of `or` in their ordered query negates it anyway. As for the second part of my answer, using `or` in place of `and` in my query would get all the 'a' people and all the 'b' people, not just those with 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: It's not out of confusion - if a name contains both an `a` and a `b`, then it could be something like `brian` or `gabrielle`. So, `%a%b%` or `%b%a%`. Their only mistake was to include a space in their patterns. Whether it makes sense to do that is another matter! As for the latter part of your answer - apologies, I thought you were referring to the OPs first query, rather than an amendment to your own query.

Comment: Casting to lower case is important, because the only matching `dname` in the sample data is `Bhavika` :)

Comment: But, question is that those names who have a word a and b.. like kunal = here comes a, in my name. so my name appears.. like this for every name...

Answer (score 2):

Removing the space before the second letter in your query should work:

```
select * from distributor where dname like '%b%a%' or dname like '%a%b%'
```